# jQuery code needed

Tags: jquery

How do I make an image or flash object run immediately when a webpage is opened and then give the option to close it?
Can this be done using jQuery?
If so can anyone show me how?

Comment: Well there isn't much of a learning curve if someone just gives you the code...

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this.  Autoplaying things is awful and will make people want to leave your website.

If you must do this, then you don't need jQuery (or any JS for that matter) to run the flash file.  Autoplaying and closing can all be done just with the flash object.

I don't know what you mean by an image running however.

Comment: I want it like when someone opens the site.. something like a greetings card comes in front and when they close it is gone and the original site is shown.

Comment: I am telling you this is terrible and people hate it!  Anyway, if you really still want to do it, then I can post another answer that will explain how to do it with some level of detail.  This is not exactly a trivial thing to do, especially if you want to have fancy animations associated with the image.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery-ui dialog to present : 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

or jquery tools http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html enable load:true

Comment: Thanx a lot! that was a lot of help..

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have seen this thing on another page and you wish to use it too. I'll recommend you to use firefox browser with it's addons for web developers. First of all you have to try: [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/), but take a look on "web developer" and "IE Tab" addons too

Those tools will help you to learn from others code.

Good luck!